# Get Color from int

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors

I'm displaying a histogram for a grayscale image and I would like to draw each line with its respective color. For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
{
  Color c=getcolor(i);
  drawline(c,x,y,...);
}
```

I want something like the getcolor function above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private static Color getcolor(int grayScale)
{
   return Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
}
```

Comment: That should be Color.FromRgb, not from Argb.

Comment: @vcsjones and his upvoters: false, no such method exists, and `Argb` has a 3-parameter overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx

Comment: I see; you are using System.Drawing.Color. I was thinking of the WPF System.Windows.Media.Color type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color_methods.aspx